How to mirror an ST7735 1.8" TFT display from the Raspberry Pi 5?
I recently bought one of those cheap ST7735 1.8" TFT LCD display modules, and I would like to find out if it is possible to mirror the Raspberry Pi display output to this mini screen. I know this is not very practical but I would still like to know if it is possible, and if so how. If this is not feasible, is it possible to wire an HDMI cable to the ST7735 screen headers so that I could connect it to my Pi via HDMI? Thanks!

does the  ST7735 have an HDMI input?

@jsotola No. It has a bunch of pins on the rear side and I want to know if I can connect those pins to an HDMI cable so that the display can be used as a screen that my Raspberry Pi can mirror its display onto. The pins the display has are: VCC, GND, CS, RST, DC, SDA, and CLK. The screen uses the SPI peripheral for communication with a controller (in this case a Raspberry Pi 5).

no, you cannot.
